# Pause mouseup/click until $.get is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

On my client page I want to execute my function each time user click something. Function send this element tag name to database. To avoid overwriting client page click event handlers I use `mousedown`. My idea:

```
jQuery('body').on('mousedown', function(event){
    var that = event.target,
        thatTag = event.target.nodeName;

    jQuery.get( 
        "http://example.com",
        { parameter: thatTag },
        function() {
            //It hasn't time to execute, because mouseup is auto executed and click action change location (if I click anchor)
        }
    );
});
```

So, is there any option to pause/block `mouseup`/`click` until my GET action is done?

Comment: You have to continue execution your function in $.get callback and don't invent a wheel

Comment: Maybe I wrong explain this. My GET action hasn't time to execute. I want pause mouseup/click only until GET isn't done. After that I want mouseup/click back to execute normal client actions.

Comment: you can put this code in a seperate function and call that function first in your previously written click event handler function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to unbind your `mousedown` handler when it is first executed, then re-bind once again when the `.get` function completes:

```
$(function() {
    // On page load, bind the first instance of the event
    $("body").on("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
});

function handleMouseDown(event) {
    // Detach the event so that is isn't handled again until the .get finishes
    $("body").off("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    var that = event.target,
        thatTag = event.target.nodeName;

    jQuery.get( 
        "http://example.com",
        { parameter: thatTag },
        function() {
            // Re-attach the event now that the .get has finished
            $("body").on("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
        }
    );
}
```